# DataGridViewCheckBox CheckedChange Event

Tags: c#, checkbox

I added Checkboxcolumn near my columns.
i googling a lot but i cant find a good answer.

I Want to make `Btn_Edit.Visiable=false;` if checkbox checked count is up to 1.
after my researches i go to Use CellContentClick event but it isn't work fine.

My Code:

```
private void GrdVw_Reception_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GrdVw_Reception.CurrentCellAddress.X == 0)
        {
            int UpTpOne = 0;
            bool flag = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < GrdVw_Reception.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(GrdVw_Reception.Rows[i].Cells["checkColumn"].Value) == true)
                {
                    UpTpOne = UpTpOne + 1;

                    if (UpTpOne == 1)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (flag == true)
            {
                Btn_Edit.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Btn_Edit.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this step when i run the program and click on checkboxes for first Btn_Edit dont go to true and for secound click Btn_Edit.Visiable go to true.

I want checkedchange event or an event that when i click on checkbox go to event codes in that moment.

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Declare `UpByOne` outside of the method, otherwise it is getting reset to zero every time the method is called.

Comment: i do it but i dont see any changes. @radarbob

Comment: This event working by clicking and our codes working with value of checkboxes..when i click on checkbox compiler go to codes and in this time value of checkbox isnt true .... it means code go to work correctly in secound click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void GrdVw_Reception_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GrdVw_Reception.CurrentCellAddress.X == 0)
            {

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(GrdVw_Reception.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == false)
                {
                    GrdVw_Reception.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                else
                {
                    GrdVw_Reception.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = CheckState.Unchecked;
                }

                int UpTpOne = 0;

                bool flag = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < GrdVw_Reception.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(GrdVw_Reception.Rows[i].Cells["checkColumn"].Value) == true)
                    {
                        UpTpOne++;

                        if (UpTpOne == 1)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (UpTpOne == 0)
                {
                    Btn_DelRecord.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    Btn_DelRecord.Visible = true;
                }

                if (flag == true)
                {
                    Btn_Edit.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Btn_Edit.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

In this code i made value of checkbox to true by code and then counting number of checkboxescell that has been checked.
I wanted make visiable of Btn_Edit go to false if the checked boxes number is up to one and.....

You should make checkbox tick to ticked and value of cell to true by code because when you click on gridviewcellcheckbox for first, the row go to selecting and in secound click the value going to be true.

I googled a lot but can't reach any good answer and this code is a total of my thinking if you have any good idea for do it better please call me.

Answer (score 0):

I proved it myself and had to do this to work:

```
     private void GrdVw_Reception_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {
         if(e.ColumnIndex == TheColumnIndexOfTheCheckBoxColumn){
             bool currentValue = !(bool)GrdVw_Reception.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
             GrdVw_Reception.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = currentValue;
            GrdVw_Reception.EndEdit();
            MessageBox.Show("Value " + currentValue.ToString());

         }
     }
```

When the even click happens the value haven't change, so, i changed it myself and call EndEdit() method of the dataGridView. It works that way.

Comment: I Write me codes in CellValueChanged but should do Two click on checkboxes to make Btn_Edit.visiable=true;

Comment: This event working by clicking and our codes working with value of checkboxes..when i click on checkbox compiler go to codes and in this time value of checkbox isnt true .... it means code go to work correctly in secound click

Comment: *"...should do two click on checkboxes..." Do you mean (a) click the same checkbox twice or (b) two different boxes are checked.

Comment: @radarbob its not important tha i check which checkbox...its not diffrent that i click which chekcbox ... i should click twice to btn_Edit.visiable go to true